# Android App asks to force close on Emulator on Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: android, android-emulator, flash-builder

I am new to Android app development and using Flash Builder 4.6. My apps work fine on the desktop, but after installing the app in the emulator and trying to open it, I get `The application process air.nameofapp has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again`. in the debug mode, I do not see any error but once I get the above error I see the following in the Logcat:

```
10-12 17:07:17.019: E/dalvikvm(452): Could not find class 'com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView$2', referenced from method com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.DoSetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeOnFormatChangeListener
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeOnFormatChangeListener(Native Method)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.surfaceChanged(AIRWindowSurfaceView.java:683)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:549)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:334)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-12 17:07:17.688: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: well, the app works just fine in the device, so i am assuming it is something to do with the emulator. thank you all